# Insert App option to call logs

Tags: android

I am developing an App that need to have an option or should i say a link when user gets the properties or menu list from call logs i.e when a user long press on an entry in call logs of phone. I have trying for hours now but not getting any useful information in internet. Please help.

[image: As shown here]

Comment: So, you wan to add an option (related to your app) in context menu appearing on log press of a contact in the Contact app?

Answer (score 1):

Adding options to context menus of other apps is really not possible. For your example specifically if you see the Contacts app over there is made by Samsung and this may vary for other OEMs and it is totally up to them how they decide to design their user interactions within their apps.

Another point to this discussion can be related to apps like WhatsApp whose options (like calling) appear in the Phone app itself. This is because it has registered itself as having that ability in its `<intent-filter>` and the Phone app itself shows all apps with that ability. However, you cannot decide what options the default Phone app shows.